# Bar chart dynamic data integration angular 2

Tags: angular, bar-chart

I'm learning new concepts in Angular 2. In this I'm trying to implement Bar Chart using ng2 charts. There m able to show static data, but not able to fetch dynamic data in it.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<canvas baseChart
          [data]="pieChartData"
          [colors]="myColors" 
          [labels]="pieChartLabels"
          [chartType]="pieChartType"
          (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
          (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
 </canvas>
```

And in Component.ts file,

```
public pieChartData: number[] = [25, 500, 100, 200];
```

In this pieChartData, instead of "25", if I pass object in it, then in the UI that particular section will got hidden/not display.

The service API is :

```
getCustomerChartInfo() {
    let data: any = {}

    this.service.getCustomerChartInfo(data).subscribe(
      body => this.mapSettingsData(body),
      err => console.log(err));
  }
  mapSettingsData(body) {
    // debugger;
    if (body.isListException == true || body.isException == 'true') {
      if (body.message == undefined) {
        alert("Something went wrong . Unable to fetch list");
        return false;
      } else {
        alert(body.message); return false;
      }
    } else {

      this.totalCustomers = body.totalCustomersInAllBranches;
      console.log("value", this.totalCustomers)
  }
```

In this console log, I'm able to print number.! 
i.e. this.totalcustomers = 3

Any Idea or hint will be appreciable. Thanks. :)

Comment: Not sure what you expect but, `number[] != object`. You can't pass in an object to array of numbers... Show us your service and JSON output of that data from your service

Comment: Hello, can you check Question again, I have edited again. :)

Comment: Your Canvas data in the DOM loads then you are assigning an object. at what point you replace the "25" with an object? Can you please put an example there. Thanks

Comment: @MrH Yea, actually i want to replace that "25" and all numbers dynamically  i.e., data coming from server only. And I want to replace those numbers on ngOnInit(){}.

Comment: ok, when do you trigger the data call? at the `ngOnInit`

Comment: @MrH Yes at the ngOnInit , I have called an API service which is "getCustomerChartInfo()", which I have mentioned in the Question(Service API). And from that in Else part of Mapsettings, I have stored the value in this.totalCustomers. Now If I put this.totalcustomers in pieChartData, that particular section will gone.

Comment: What does your `totalCustomers` output? Include that in your question to please.

Comment: @12seconds hello, I have mention that in question, Can you check it again ? :)

Comment: There's your issue, 3 is not an array.

Comment: @12seconds ohh!! then how can I do ? can you help ?

Comment: The issue is how your sever side is returning the data, from the look of it you are just returning `int` not array of `int`